# Continuous differentiability of atan2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) defined on the plane, minus the origin and the negative $x$-axis, as the unique $\theta$ such that $-\pi<\theta<\pi$ and
$$ x = r \cos \theta, \qquad y=r \sin \theta$$
where $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I would like to prove rigorously that `atan2` is a continuously differentiable function of $x$ and $y$ in the domain above. Two approaches which I think don't work:

1. Implicit differentiation: this doesn't help since the implicit function theorem is only local. So it cannot help us prove that `atan2` is a single $C^1$ function over the entire domain described above.
2. Replace $\mbox{atan2}(x,y)$ by $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$: this throws away information about the signs of $y$ and $x$ and hence cannot represent $\mbox{atan2}$ over the entire domain. Also, $y/x$ is undefined when $x=0$, but there are such points in the domain.

I would be grateful for an outline of the proof or a reference to a book where it can be found.

Comment: Do you mean "negative $y$-axis" or "negative $x$-axis"? I think the points you are trying to avoid are at $\theta = \pm\pi,$ which would occur at $x < 0, y= 0.$

Comment: @DavidK Thanks. Correcting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm referring to the following figure:

[image]

If $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ then $$\tan{\theta\over2}={y\over r+x}\ .$$
It follows that the principal value of the argument ("atan2" in some circles) is given by
$${\rm Arg}(x,y)=\theta=2{\theta\over2}=2\arctan{y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}\ .$$
Note that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\ne0$ in the domain in question. Computation gives
$$\nabla\arg(x,y)=\left({-y\over x^2+y^2}, \ {x\over x^2+y^2}\right)\ ,$$
which is also well defined on the negative $x$-axis.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that one answer is also on Wikipedia, in the article on the [arg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29) function

$$\mbox{atan2}(x,y) = 2\tan^{-1} \left({ y \over {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}}\right)$$

where the values of $\tan^{-1}$ are taken in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

The right-hand side is well-defined and has continuous partial derivatives in the domain in the question.

Verifying the formula above requires using trignometric identities. I wonder if a more direct argument is also possible?